# How to print last few contents in a line?

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, awk, ln

I have a file that has lines shown below,

```
ta=/*92/*39/*1/*649/*12
ta=/*92/*12/*4/*342/*90
ta=/*92/*33/*9/*455/*3
ta=/*92/*12/*3/*649/*25
ta=/*92/*99/*7/*649/*7
```

and so on.

I want a file that will have the output shown below,

```
*12
*90
*3
*25
*7
```

That means I just want to print only the last part, after the 4th slash.

I have tried `cat filename | awk '{print $1}'`. It was giving output

```
ta=/*92/*39/*1/*649/*12
```

But my requirement was to get only the `*12` number.

Comment: `sed 's|.*/||'`

Comment: will it print only the last number what i want? i mean, *12

*90

*3

*25

*7

Comment: This is horrible formatting for a question. Please format it properly after reading the help here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Did you try it? That `s///`ubstitution will remove all characters found on an input line up to and including the last occurring `/`. Do `echo bla1/bla2/bla3 | sed 's|.*/||'` and see for yourself. If you want the leading hashes just do `sed 's|.*/|#|'` instead.

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting of your question; now please [edit] it so its meaning is clear.  Do you want the `#` characters in your output or not?  (If yes, what do you want to do with lines that don't begin with, or don't contain, `#`?)  Do you want the last part (as you have said), the part after the 4th slash (as you have said), or the part after the 5th slash (as you have shown)?

Comment: I want only that part which is after the fifth slash. That is , for the first entry its *12, for the second entry its *90 and so on. No, I don't want # characters in my output file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using cut, like: `cut -d/ -f6 file`

Comment: could you please explain in detail? why f6? will it print only the last number? I mean the output what i have mentioned in my question?

Comment: f6 means field six; d/ means split the line into fields at the / characters. It will produce the desired output from your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `awk`, as you seem to indicate in your question, you could set the *field separator* to `/` and then print the last field

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -o '\*[0-9]\+$' file
```

Output:

```
*12
*90
*3
*25
*7
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that there’s some ambiguity regarding exactly what you want.  If you
want *everything* after the fifth slash, use

```
sed -r 's|^([^/]*/){5}||;t;s|.*||' filename
```

For the somewhat pathological, assumption-questioning,
boundary-challenging input of

```
ta=/*92/*39/*1/*649/*12
ta=/*92/*12/*4/*342/*90
foo/The/quick/brown/fox
bar/jumps/over/the/lazy/dog
/Once/upon/a/midnight/dreary
/as/I/pondered/weak/and/weary
```

this will give the following output:

```
*12
*90

dog
dreary
and/weary
```

Note that the third line of the output is blank,
because the third line of the input has only four slashes,
so there is nothing after the fifth one
(because there ***is*** no fifth slash). 
And the sixth (last) line of the output contains a `/`,
because the sixth line of the input has six slashes,
and “*everything* after the fifth slash” includes the sixth slash.